# Toolbar/AppbarLayout pushing view offscreen. How keep view within screen bounds?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I asked this question previously but I think I worded it poorly. I'm using the provided Tabbed Activity with Action Bar Tabs (with viewpager) default project layout in Android Studio 1.4 and I'm trying to get a button to appear at the bottom of my fragment that is displayed in one of the tabs. The issue I'm having it that that my AppBarLayout/Toolbar in my activity is pushing part of my fragment view offscreen. Here is what I am seeing.

[My fragment in the editor with a button aligned with the bottom of its parent relative view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FJ2E.png)

[How this fragment looks when displayed inside the activity on my device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCG0Z.png) As you can see the button in the relative view is rendered off screen (I know because I can add padding below the button and it will eventually appear on screen) and I think this is being caused by the AppBarLayout/Toolbar pushing it there.

Here is my fragment xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the parent activity.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?  attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Does anyone know how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was apparently an issue with the CoordinatorLayout I was using in my activity XML, switching to a RelativeLayout fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you still see the toolbar animate?